# openpyxl library highlight multiple cells in spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

to get to the point, I am running some tests and wrote a program that generates spreadsheets for data analysis.

For each test, there are certain numbers already written to the spreadsheet at random locations (I wrote the program to store these numbers on the side as a list of strings) that I want to highlight/flag with a colour.

I have the following lines of code written in python with the openpyxl library:

```
if trackPgmBits:
    ws = wb['Pgm tracking']
    ws.append([''])
    for j in range(len(pgm_tracking_summary)):
        for i in range(len(pgm_tracking_summary[j])):
            if analog_tracking_summary[j][i] == '':
                pgm_tracking_summary[j][i] = ''
        ws.append(pgm_tracking_summary[j])



    RRule = CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=highlightPgmBits, stopIfTrue = True, fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF00', end_color='FFFF00' ,fill_type='solid'))
    RRange = "A1:"+_get_column_letter(ws.max_column) + str(ws.max_row)
    ws.conditional_formatting.add(RRange, RRule)
```

The array of numbers I want to highlight is stored in the array highlightPgmBits and is passed into the program with: formula=highlightPgmBits'

**highlightPgmBits is a list of strings.

This code works when I replace with a hard-coded single value: formula=['2.4087']

This code does not work when I replace with two values hard-coded: formula=['2.4087', '2.7']

This leads me to believe my approach is only appropriate for highlighting one number. However, there must be a way solve this problem! Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

I essentially needed to loop through every element of the list I created to make a new 'rule' for each number I wanted to highlight:

Although inefficient, it does the trick. I added different colour coatings as well according to specific conditions I wanted to monitor.

```
if trackPgmBits:
    ws = wb['Pgm tracking']
    print 'highlightPgmBits'
    print highlightPgmBits
    ws.append([''])
    for j in range(len(pgm_tracking_summary)):
        for i in range(len(pgm_tracking_summary[j])):
            if analog_tracking_summary[j][i] == '':
                pgm_tracking_summary[j][i] = ''
        ws.append(pgm_tracking_summary[j])

    for j in range(len(highlightPgmBits)):
        if highlightPgmBits_Cycle < (cycles-1)/4:
            RRule = CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=[highlightPgmBits[j]], stopIfTrue = True, fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFA600', end_color='FFA600' ,fill_type='solid'))
            RRange = "A1:"+_get_column_letter(ws.max_column) + str(ws.max_row)
            ws.conditional_formatting.add(RRange, RRule)
        elif (highlightPgmBits_Cycle[j] < (cycles-1)/2) and (highlightPgmBits_Cycle[j] >= (cycles-1)/4):
            RRule = CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=[highlightPgmBits[j]], stopIfTrue = True, fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF00', end_color='FFFF00',fill_type='solid'))
            RRange = "A1:"+_get_column_letter(ws.max_column) + str(ws.max_row)
            ws.conditional_formatting.add(RRange, RRule)
        elif (highlightPgmBits_Cycle[j] < (cycles-1)*(3/4)) and (highlightPgmBits_Cycle[j] >= (cycles-1)/2):
            RRule = CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=[highlightPgmBits[j]], stopIfTrue = True, fill = PatternFill(start_color='00F7FF', end_color='00F7FF' ,fill_type='solid'))
            RRange = "A1:"+_get_column_letter(ws.max_column) + str(ws.max_row)
            ws.conditional_formatting.add(RRange, RRule)
        else: 
            RRule = CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=[highlightPgmBits[j]], stopIfTrue = True, fill = PatternFill(start_color='73FF00', end_color='73FF00' ,fill_type='solid'))
            RRange = "A1:"+_get_column_letter(ws.max_column) + str(ws.max_row)
            ws.conditional_formatting.add(RRange, RRule)
```

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AM8K.png)

Please comment if you are trying to implement something similar and my post seems confusing, I can clarify! Also, if you know a more efficient solution, please share!